# WCF - Unable to translate Unicode character \uDEC0 at index 0 to specified code page

Tags: c#, wcf, unicode

We are hosting two WCF Services that are hosted via two separate Windows Service.

One of these services is accessible remotely and talks to the other, which is only accessible locally. The communication between the outside and the first service works fine (via *NetTcpBinding*), however, when the first one tries to talk to the second service locally (via *NetNamedPipeBinding*), we get the following error:

> Unable to translate Unicode character \uDEC0 at index 0 to specified
>   code page

After days of searching, we found out that if we changed the service's log on as account from Local System to Network Service, it works perfectly fine. We also tried to use *NetTcpBinding* for the local communication between the two services to no avail.

It is really strange and my question is, since from this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) it looks like the Local System account has more privileges, what is going there? Why am I seeing this issue?

Comment: Well, [\uDEC0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/dec0/index.htm) is in fact an invalid Unicode character.  Can you share any additional information, such as 1) If you are getting an exception, what is the complete `ToString()` output of the exception?  2) What call are you making that causes the error?

Comment: How come it works when launched as a user or using the Network Service account? Any clue?